# How can I get Python working in an existing NetBeans?

Tags: python, netbeans

I'm running a standalone ZIP of NetBeans 7.3.1 and I am wondering if it is to get Python support going with this. I know there is a standalone download for Python support, but I was hoping I could get it going in my install. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check this out: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_7

It provides decent plugins that allow for some python and jython dev functionality.

Edit:

In case you don't know how to add the plugin source in Netbeans you need to navigate to:

Tools > Plugins > Settings > click the "Add" button and add

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

as the URL. The python plugins will then be visible under "Available Plugins".

Comment: Is there a way to do it without converting the build to nightly (apparently that's a byproduct of adding that plugin source)?

Comment: Never mind, I restarted the IDE and waited a second on the update screen and it fixed itself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped! I didn't actually know that this is what caused my Netbeans convert to the build to nightly, how did you revert back?

Comment: @Mafro34 not sure if you can "revert back", I'm installing two NetBeans not one stable for HTML5 development and another one for Python hope it works well.

Comment: Hmmm... I would like to know if there is some way of installing the Python support for the old good 7.3.1 version, because 7.4 only runs under JDK 7, and I need to upgrade my entire MacOS Snow Leopard system just to have Netbeans 7.4 running ! And I don't want to do that just to get Python running on Netbeans...